# Generate all strings having characters a,b or c with length equal to n with atmost 1 b and 2 c

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, backtracking

Generate all strings with the following constrains

- Length: n
- Characters allowed: a,b,c
- At most one b
- At most two c

I have written the following code

```
def generate(s,counta,countb,countc,n,result):
    if counta+countb+countc==n:
        print(counta,countb,countc)
        result.append(s)
        print(s)
        return
    if counta+countb+countc<n and counta<=n:
        generate(s+"a",counta+1,countb,countc,n,result)
    if counta+countb+countc<n and countb<=1:
        generate(s+"b",counta+1,countb+1,countc,n,result)
    if counta+countb+countc<n and countc<=2:
        generate(s+"c",counta,countb,countc+1,n,result)


result=[]
generate("",0,0,0,3,result)
print(result)
```

I get the following result which I don't understand why. Some strings of length less than n are getting added to the result.

```
['aaa', 'aac', 'ab', 'aca', 'acc', 'ba', 'bc', 'caa', 'cac', 'cb', 'cca', 'ccc']
```

**Update Code: (Working)**

```
def generate(s,counta,countb,countc,n,result):
if counta+countb+countc==n:
    # print(counta,countb,countc)
    result.append(s)
    # print(s)
    return
if counta+countb+countc<n and counta<=n:
    generate(s+"a",counta+1,countb,countc,n,result)
if counta+countb+countc<n and countb<1:
    generate(s+"b",counta,countb+1,countc,n,result)
if counta+countb+countc<n and countc<2:
    generate(s+"c",counta,countb,countc+1,n,result)

result=[]
generate("",0,0,0,3,result)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bac', 'bca', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb']
```

Comment: you made a small typo. `generate(s+"b",counta+1,countb+1,countc,n,result)` should not be adding `counta+1`. Voting to close as typo. it's why you're adding 2 length strings, because in that block, the counts end up reaching 3 prematurely due to double increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your logic is off; for example, `countb<=1` means you could already *have* a `b`, so you shouldn't necessarily add another.  Also, in that call, you are adding 1 to both `countb` and `countc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the issues. It works fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a more cleaner solution, then the below code should do the job. The constraint logic is totally separated out from the generation logic. This way the constraint can be added independant of the generation logic.

```
from itertools import product

n = 3

for i in map(''.join, product('abc', repeat=n)):
    if i.count('b') <= 1 and i.count('c') <= 2:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bac
bca
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbc
cca
ccb
```

Comment: Shorter to write; potentially *much* slower to run.